# Converting a large string of hex to decimal on windows

Tags: windows, conversion

I have a long string of hex characters which I need to be converted to ascii , decimal and several other formats. The hexcode is separated by brackets and I wanted to know if there is any free tool for the windows platform which will do this job for me?

Comment: how about something like this? http://www.dolcevie.com/js/converter.html
If you need it to be code, take that code (view source) and convert it to you're preferred language.

Comment: I would like to set the delimiting character to {} so a software which helps me set that would be way more useful

Comment: Yes, there're a few built into Windows itself (not ready-made though). You can use PowerShell like [so](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/09/09/convert-hexadecimal-to-ascii-using-powershell.aspx) or even VBScript. If you're looking for code, get started with it, then ask for help over on StackOverflow.

Comment: you want some sort of utility? it wouldn't be hard to make one but you gotta tell me what language you want it in.

Comment: OKay. I guess I have to write some sort of script. I was wondering if there was an existing software already. Thats all. Script wise perl seems fine